# Could anyone solve this challenge problem on series, very similar to the Fibonacci Sequence? an = an-1 + an-2 - an-3.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

It is given that a<sub>1</sub> = $0.2$, a<sub>2</sub> = $0.3$, a<sub>3</sub> = $0.5$
and a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n-1</sub> + a<sub>n-2</sub> - a

n-3

P = a<sub>2013</sub>

Q = a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>3</sub> + ... + a<sub>2013</sub>

R is the minimum value of i such that a<sub>i</sub> > 2013.

S is the number of possible values for i such that ai

 is an integer for i $\leqslant$ i $\leqslant$ 2013.

Find the values of P, Q, R and S.

(It should be able to be solved without the use of a calculator.)

---

- I got the answer 301.8 for P, by realising that the value of the terms increases by 0.1 and 0.2 in an alternating way.

P = $(2013-1) / 2 * (0.1+0.2)$ = $1006 * 0.3$ = $301.8$

Comment: I would consider writing a simple program to answer this question

Comment: @philbo_baggins “It should be able to be solved without the use of a calculator.” Writing a simple program _is_ using a fancy calculator.

Comment: @amd whoops didn't read closely enough

Answer (score 2):

Your method is pretty close to optimal, I'd say.

If you want another approach, note that the characteristic polynomial is $$x^3-x^2-x+1=(x-1)^2(x+1)$$ so the general solution to the recursion is $$A+B (-1)^n+Cn$$

Using your given initial conditions we see that $$a_n=\frac 1{40}-\frac 1{40}(-1)^n+\frac 3{20}n$$  And you can now sum and solve analytically.

Note, however, that the simplicity of this solution really is a lucky accident (or a contrivance of the problem).  Most cubics have unpleasant solutions so this analytic method would return a very complex formula.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution as the problem is designed to be completed within 8 minutes by a group of 3 15-year-olds as a challenge problem.

Comment: @MingPokNg I suspect that you’re expected to spot the simple pattern of the sequence.

Comment: For $15$ year olds, I'm sure they were meant to spot the pattern you spotted.

Comment: But then how could they proceed to calculating the sum of the series? It seems like the terms don't cancel out.

Comment: Oh, your method handles that perfectly well. You have shown that each $a_n$ is just $a_0$ plus a bunch of $.1's$ plus a bunch of $.2's$.  (roughly speaking, $\frac n2$) of each.  You just have to get the count right and then sum.  Essentially you are recovering the formula I wrote down.  I assume these kids know about the triangular numbers  $\sum_{i=1}^n i$.